# Orange3 Python Widget i can't totalize the values of a column marked as meta

Tags: variables, types, orange

When trying to totalize the values of a variable/column marked as meta from Python widget in Orange3 is not working. How can i make operations with the columns with continuous variable marked as meta?.

```
import Orange
from Orange.data import ContinuousVariable, DiscreteVariable, Domain, Table
import numpy as np

data_copy = in_data.copy()
total = np.sum(data_copy[:,('meta_variable')])

print(data_copy[:,('meta_variable')])
>>>
[[] {0.002199999999999980},
 [] {-0.000199999999999978},
 [] {-0.001199999999999870},
 [] {-0.005300000000000080},
 [] {-0.003500000000000060}]

print(total)
>>>
0.00000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metas are stored as a numpy array `.metas`. of an `Orange.data.Table`.

First, I'll construct an example dataset with a numeric meta:

```
import Orange
data = Orange.data.Table("iris")
domain_w_metas = Orange.data.Domain(
    data.domain.attributes[1:],
    data.domain.class_vars,
    [data.domain.attributes[0]])
data = data.transform(domain_w_metas)
print(data.domain)
```

We see that now we have a single meta, "sepal length":

```
[sepal width, petal length, petal width | iris] {sepal length}
```

In our case we are looking for the first meta, so we can simply do:

```
first_column = data.metas[:, 0]
print(numpy.sum(first_column))
```

Answer (score -1):

I try to select only the wavenumber of a spectra with a python script but I've a probleme with the in_data.domain. 
I have this kind of result "ContinuousVariable(name='1748.804574', number_of_decimals=3)" but I would like only extract the value 1748 cm-1 in a numpy array.

Thank you

Nicolas

Comment: This does not look like the answer to this question. If you have a problem, ask a new question.